# Permission error when formating USB sticks with GParted

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, gparted, ubuntu-studio

After upgrading to 16.04, I am no longer able to formate USB-sticks for normal use as Fat32 (or Fat16 for the small ones), any copying to the USB gives a Read Only error:
[image]
The permissions for the groupe is set to Read Only, after the latest upgrade to 16.04, used to work just fine!
[image]
Any use of chmod do not change the permissions, and trying to use GParted to fix the partition does not change anything!
And I am the owner of the files and device, but copying insist of using the Group credentials - which is read only!

Comment: What is the file system o your USB storages?

Comment: Sorry Forgot to mention, I am trying to reset the sticks after having used them for various *buntu  Live ISO's, and for compatibility reasons I try FAT 16 and 32, with the same result - prior to the upgrade it worked every time!

Comment: For some reason formatting to NTFS (which my settopbox and BlueRay player reconciles  seams to work ! ( thanks to wair92)

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of things and getting a lot of errors like this:
[image]
[image]
I stumbled upon the option of changing the UUID number of the Sticks!
For some reason the rights to the file-system hangs on the UUID - and survive reformation!!
[image]

Chainge the UUID before risking to lock the USB-stick up totally (see abowe)! [image]
This will get rid of all the Read only restrictions for all users in both Fat and Ntfs !!!
Wonder where our devises hide this information, cause it isn't on the PC - it is on the sticks somewhere - moving to an other PC keeps the problem just fine (sucks) But changing the UUID breaks the chain!! and the stick works again!

Now I just have to resurrect the USB-stick that gives all these errors - changing partition tables too much can wreck havoc!

Comment: How you changed the UUID ?

Comment: You change the UUID from GParted in the Partition tab, next to last option called NEW UUID.

Comment: Unfortunately that option is not active.

Comment: I have added to my answer on your question.