# Disk is write protected after making it into a live usb

Tags: live-usb, gparted, usb-drive

I have a sandisk 8GB USB 2.0 pendrive. After making it into a Linux live boot disk, it turned into a read only disk. I have tested many solutions. I can access all the files in it and it reads without any problem. Same error when I checked using windows.

Can I correct it?

Answer (score 3):

I had almost the same issue, it turns out the Group permissions are read-only, and you cannot get them right again  -  UNLESS you change the UUID of your USB-stick.

See my question and answer here:
[USB stick read only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810944/permission-error-when-formating-usb-sticks-with-gparted)

After changing the UUID and reformatting the disk everything works normally again!
Do try without reformatting, and then change the group-permissions to Read-Write!  Have not tried this, but it should work!!

So that didn't work, then we have to use the big Terminal hammer:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>  brings forth the terminal so enter:

> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=512 count=16

This will erase the start of the USB-stick. this solution I got here:
[Refurbishing the USB-stick](http://goo.gl/nWXA61)

Now you should be able to format it to fat32 - or something else without any further trouble!

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for my stick. Nulled it entirely, new partition table, new partition, new UUID and with the next mount it was still read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Given almost the same problem as the OP I tried Ken Mollerup's solution - twice - but it did not seem to do the trick.

However after killing nautilus (`killall nautilus` in the console) and then restarting it the issue was solved. It seems that [Launchpad Bug 1021375](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1021375) affects or affected this as well.

Sadly the question remains if I had to do both or if restarting nautilus was sufficient.